# Airport express and airplay. Is there a way to auto turn on amplifier?

Tags: music, airplay

I would like to stream music from my Apple devices to my kitchen.
I've got an old amplifier and passive speakers.

I know that I can simply connect my airport express to the LAN or WiFi and to the ampli as line input, but I would like the ampli to turn on only when there is a line input signal, and then automatically turn off after an idle time, in a way similar to many Subwoofers.

In this way only the AirPort Express will be always powered.

Is there a device or a simple way to do this job?

Comment: That would be a functionality of the amplifier. Technically feasible, but probably not something which is in high demand.

Answer (score 1):

While in terms of the specificity of the desired *implementation* I agree with @patrix, you could get the desired *solution* if you're open to reframing how it all gets handled. I'd say the easiest (but somewhat costly) way to get the desired behavior is to get a Logitech Harmony remote.

If the amplifier pre-dates remote controls, you might need to think further outside the box and look into a wifi/BT-enabled power switch (plug the amplifier into said switch and have the hardware power toggle on the amp always set to "On"; give the signal to the power switch to let the power flow through it, the amp then remotely powers on).

Things get very interesting in these days of "Internet of Things"… :-)

Comment: Belkin's WeMo IoT product line has a [wifi-enabled power switch](http://www.belkin.com/us/F7C029-Belkin/p/P-F7C029/), for example…